# How to create custom widget and use it in Qt Designer?

Tags: c++, qt

I extremely need to create my custom widget and use it inside QtDesigner ( promoting QWidget to my widget ). I have never done it before, and can't google anything useful. Widget i need to get is just square box with few QLabel and QLineEdit objects. For this moment i have the following code:

```
#include "customwidget01.h"
#include "qlabel.h"
#include "qlineedit.h"
#include "QGridLayout"
customWidget01::customWidget01(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    QString textSheets = "QLabel,QLineEdit {width:60;height:20;max-width:60;max-height:20;;min-width:60;min-height:20;}";
    QString widgetSheet = "customWidget01 {width:200;height:200;max-width:200;max-height:200;;min-width:120;min-height:200;}";
    this->setStyleSheet(widgetSheet + textSheets);
    QLabel *label1= new QLabel(this);
    label1->setText("1st arg");
    QLabel *label2 = new QLabel(this);
    label2->setText("2nd arg");
    QLabel *label3= new QLabel(this);
    label3->setText("3rd arg");
    QLabel *label4= new QLabel(this);
    label4->setText("4th arg");
    QLineEdit *line1 = new QLineEdit(this);
    line1->setPlaceholderText("enter 1st arg");
    QLineEdit *line2 = new QLineEdit(this);
    line2->setPlaceholderText("enter 2nd arg");
    QLineEdit *line3 = new QLineEdit(this);
    line3->setPlaceholderText("enter 3rd arg");
    QLineEdit *line4 = new QLineEdit(this);
    line4->setPlaceholderText("enter 4th arg");
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout();
    this->setLayout(layout);
    layout->setVerticalSpacing(10);
    layout->setHorizontalSpacing(10);
    layout->addWidget(label1,0,0);
    layout->addWidget(label2,1,0);
    layout->addWidget(label3,2,0);
    layout->addWidget(label4,3,0);
    layout->addWidget(line1,0,1);
    layout->addWidget(line2,1,1);
    layout->addWidget(line3,2,1);
    layout->addWidget(line4,3,1);
    this->setVisible(true);
}
```

My problems are:

1. cant draw border around widget itself
2. vertical and horizontal    spacings do not work

Used QtDesigner for GUI all the time - not really familiar with gui creation in plain code.

Comment: Why do you *have to* use designer? You could just instantiate your widget in C++ and add it to whatever layout (or similar) you need, from code..

Comment: Adding widget is not a problem at all for me. The problem is that i can't make widget from code look nice (it doesn't have border for some reason, qgridlayout stretches to much (setVerticalSpacing(10) and setHorizontalSpacing(10)) do not work at all.

Comment: Your problem is a bit unclear: are you having a problem with your widget, or with Qt Designer?

Comment: Also, if you are comfortable with Designer, why don't you create your custom widget with Designer? It's better anyway to split your UI to several Designer forms (and use promote feature or hand-written parent widget to use them together).

Comment: @faspowa Qt Designer does not show what you implement by code since it only takes as ingredients the plugin of the generic widget + .ui, everything that you modify different from the above will only be shown when you compile and execute your program. For example if your code changes the color of some element then Qt Designer will not show it since it does not know it but if you change the color using Qt Designer it will show it since you will have modified the .ui.

Comment: Also, you can see how your C++ code is different from C++ generated from Designer .ui file, to get an idea of what's wrong with your code.

Comment: @faspowa If you want your custom code widget to be shown in Qt Designer then you must implement a plugin, compile and install it, IMHO for your inexperience will bring more problems than benefits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let me help you in order to get beautiful interface you need to learn CSS
I will show you how it works
that's what you have right now

[image]

This means that you do not correctly write the CSS code

```
QString textSheets = "QLabel,QLineEdit {width:60;height:20;max-width:60;max-height:20;;min-width:60;min-height:20;}";
QString widgetSheet = "customWidget01 {width:200;height:200;max-width:200;max-height:200;;min-width:120;min-height:200;}";
this->setStyleSheet(widgetSheet + textSheets);  // does not work
```

I will exchange these lines for it

```
QString textSheets = "QLineEdit{ border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: red green black rgb(127,255,10); }"
                      "QLabel  { border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: green black rgb(10,255,180) rgb(180,10,158); }" ;

setStyleSheet(textSheets);
```

and that's what result

[image]

to resize you just need to do so

```
//label1->setMinimumSize(150,50);
label1->setFixedSize(150,50);
//label1->setMaximumSize(150,50);
//label1->setMidLineWidth(150);
```

and that's what result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a `QWidget` in design mode.
2. Right click it and select `Promote to...` from the context menu.
3. Write the name (`customWidget01`) of your from `QWidget` derived class into `Promoted class name`.
4. Make sure the generated text in `Header file` is correct.
5. Click add.
6. Select it and click promote.

Comment: thanks, but i already know how to promote a widget. my problem is new hand-made widget i am promoting to ( it looks like trash, and i can't even draw border for it by using stylesheet)